# 'qiskit' has no attribute '__qiskit_version__'

Tags: python, qiskit

as title says, I type

```
qiskit.__qiskit_version__
```

and get the error AttributeError: module 'qiskit' has no attribute '**qiskit_version**'.
I have Anaconda installed as well as pip installed qiskit and qiskit[visualization]. The jupyter notebook only works within my python file and not sure what else to do?

Comment: Possibly you've named your own script `qiskit.py`, causing it to shadow the actual module of that name.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was python was installed in 2 different locations. Had to delete both then reinstall!